# How can I get the ID of the embed message that my bot has sent?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I can use the id inside the .then but when I try to use it outside of the .then, I get undefined.

```
          var kickEmbedID;
          message.channel.send(kickEmbed).then(sentMessage => {
            sentMessage.react(message.guild.emojis.cache.get('752882746686439445'));
            sentMessage.react(message.guild.emojis.cache.get('752882888420229290'));
            kickEmbedID = sentMessage.id;
          })

          message.channel.send(kickEmbedID)
```

Comment: You're obviously using some kind of framework or library. Discord perhaps? Please [edit] your question and add the tag(s) for those items you are using above those included with JavaScript and the browser.

Comment: you need to `await` the promise otherwise the code is going to continue execution and `kickEmbedID` will still be undefined since the promise hasn't finished yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `await` the `message.channel.send` promise otherwise `reactEmbedID` will remain undefined. Try this:

```
client.on('message', async message => {
  // rest of your code
  const { id } = await message.channel.send(kickEmbed);
  console.log(id); // prints message id
});
```

See more here: https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/async-await.html#execution-with-discord-js-code